# How to implement QtWebView in a non-QML application?

Tags: qt

I am playing with Qt on Android platform, and one of major drawbacks of Qt on mobile platforms is that it's missing Web Browser component.

I found that in order to display HTML content, one can use "WebView" component: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html

Unfortunately I found 0 information on how to use this on non-QML application. Everyone is assuming your app is QML, but what if it isn't. Is there any way to use this component? How?

Comment: Strange you found "0" information .. what is wrong with _QtWebEngine_ .. [qtwebenginewidgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-module.html) search for [qt c++ web browse](https://www.google.ps/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enPS722PS722&ei=g_qJWvj0IYTHwQL1lY-ICQ&q=qt+c%2B%2B+web+browse&oq=qt+c%2B%2B+web+browse&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i22i30k1.12572.19154.0.19936.15.15.0.0.0.0.150.1856.0j15.15.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.15.1852...0j33i22i29i30k1.0.TtpJbbV2Erk)

Comment: @MohammadKanan it's very simple what is wrong with it, it simply doesn't work on Android or iOS. Web Engine is for desktop platforms only. Completely out of question here.

Comment: This is good guide [Qt User Interfaces](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/topics-ui.html)